Lamp Socket replacement on Outdoor Chandelier
What’s the best way to remove or replace a stuck lamp socket attached to a threaded tube?
Details & Pics: https://imgur.com/a/lSewhLV
The socket won’t budge—I’ve tried WD-40 and clamping with pliers, but no luck. I’m working on an outdoor chandelier that was flickering, and when I checked, I found the socket’s terminals were completely rusted. I’d like to replace it with a waterproof socket for outdoor use.
Any tips? Is it supposed to unscrew? If not, I might need to cut it from the wires and take it to a repair shop.
Thanks!

Start with a good shot of penetrating oil, some patience and a good wirie brush. You have nothing to lose since a shop would be reluctant to do a repair.

Why not just replace the entire fixture?

A real penetrating oil or transmission fluid plus acetone(1 to 1) should work better than what you are using.
Two decent size pipe wrenches with maybe cheater bars should turn it.  Will be amazed how easy stuff turns(or breaks) when you use a two or three foot bar/pipe on wrenches.
One wrench on the threads, the other on the part you want to turn.
